# runMain Boot project configuration

Tags: scala, configuration

I am trying to compile my scala project with my configuration, but it do not see the akka. I think it is because of my working directory, which is exactly to Boot.scala file, including all packages. I tried to put my working directory to its file but in this case I got ClassNotFoundException: Boot. 
Can someone can help me please.

Comment: Can you show some code

Comment: what code you want to see? I think code is not necessary here. I want to see how to create new configuration for sbtTask.

Comment: if you show your `build.sbt` and how you're trying to run your application, maybe somebody could help

Comment: build.sbt is ok, all dependencies are exist, I am sure about that, I want to know how to configure sbtTask to run with runMain Boot comand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone will find it useful, the problem was that I did not give correct path to my Boot.scala file. So, in order to work I make following, in **Tasks** field of **Run/Debug configuration**, it is necessary to write full path to Boot.scala file. For instance, `"runMain com.company.activity.service.Boot"` (the quotes are necessary). Uncheck the using sbt shell and fill **Working directory** and **Environment variables** fields. After that press **Apply** button and your project should compile well.